# Best flight connections between Amsterdam and Central America

Tags: air-travel, budget, amsterdam, central-america

My plan is to visit Central America, let's say Guatemala, Honduras, Costa Rica, Panama in 3 weeks holiday.

I still don't have the plans clear, but what I'm interested is to get the best flights for March/April.

I fly from Amsterdam (Netherlands), and I would like to know what are the best international airports connected with my city. For "Best" I mean, the cheapest, and as more direct as possible.

Comment: "Best" in what way? Cheapest? Most direct?

Comment: @Mark Mayo Cheapest is the first criteria, and then most direct

Comment: Have you tried Kayak, CheapOAir, Travelocity and such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure that this question can be answered at all but let me try.

The prices for the tickets can vary and vary widely since your timeframe includes Easter.

Since you have not specified budget or times you can look at various airlines flying from Amsterdam to see who goes directly for example:

- KLM has direct flights to Panama City, Panama Flight number 757.  Cost ???
- There is a 1 stop flight to San Jose, Costa Rica and Guatemala City via Panama City using KLM and Copa Air.

I would very seriously suggest narrowing down your timeframes and what you want to visit where to make your question more deterministic.

Comment: +1. KLM is great for that region and it is direct from Amsterdam.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it'll depend on where you fly into, and what dates and the like.

However a quick check on return flights to Tegucigalpa (capital of Honduras) reveals Delta is probably one of the cheapest and most direct - stopping only in Atlanta.  Other airlines include United and American Airlines, and fly via Miami or Houston as well.

Your best bet may be a return flight to Tegucigalpa, and a one-way from Panama back to Honduras, depending on your route, or an open-jaw flight to get back to Amsterdam.

I'd recommend [Flightfox](http://flightfox.com/) as a potential solution seeing as you have tons of possible options.  Describe what you want and the dates, and people will crowd-source you an answer (it costs money, but I've got a link in my profile that can get you a discount).  I've used it in the past on a complex flight and was amazed at what they came up with.

If you narrow your dates and a route, we may be able to help out further.